# Social Media Icons Link Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select all `ul > li > a > i` elements with a specific class and add a link attribute to them. You can go to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/InspiredPrynce/nrw6ouw0/) and understand what I mean.

```
var twitter_url = 'twitter link';
var facebook_url = 'facebook link';
var gplus_url = 'google plus link';

if ($('ul.social i').hasClass('.fa-twitter')){
    $("ul.social a:nth-child(1)").attr("href", twitter_url);
}
if ($('ul.social i').has('.fa-facebook')){
    $("ul.social a:nth-child(2)").attr("href", facebook_url);
}
if ($('ul.social i').has('.fa-google-plus')){
    $('ul.social a').attr("href", gplus_url);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
        var twitter_url = 'https://twitter.com/FameWaves_intl';
        var facebook_url = 'https://facebook.com/famewaves';
        var gplus_url = 'https://plus.google.com/famewaves';


        $('ul.social li').each(function(){
            var aLink = $(this).find('a'),
                className = $(this).find('i').prop('class');
            switch(className)
            {
                case "fa fa-twitter":
                    aLink.attr("href", twitter_url);
                    break;
                case "fa fa-facebook":
                     aLink.attr("href", facebook_url);
                    break;
                case "fa fa-google-plus":
                    aLink.attr("href", gplus_url);
                    break; 
            }

        });
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrw6ouw0/2/)